# python command only gives "Python"

Tags: python, django

[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpEms.png)

I got a terminal problem using python.
ex) when typing `python --version` and tapping Enter, my terminal only gives "Python"
all the other commands starting with "python" give "Python", without executing the command

I think it's not that complicated problem, but I don't know what keyword has to be searched.

Comment: What does the command `which python` give you?

Comment: Have you created some script in your system path called "python" which you are calling instead of the real python. if your using *nix system can you show the output of `which python` and then when you get the path show the output of `file` against that path

Comment: oh, im so sorry. i made a mistake adding a wrong python path. thank you for helping me